# Getting top 3 languages used in text using AWS comprehend

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-comprehend

I am trying to auto-detect languages used from texts using AWS Comprehend service.

Using `boto.detect_dominant_language` we only get the top dominating language in the text. Is there a way to get the top 2-3 dominant languages in text for AWS Comprehend? Could not find any info
regarding this in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the top 2-3 dominant languages in text for AWS Comprehend?

Unfortunately, no - there is no API endpoint / SDK implementation for this.